# Nginx trailing slash redirect issue

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am running a Wordpress website with Nginx + Varnish. I am getting The page isn't redirecting properly error if I am adding or removing trailing slash in the configuration file. Please suggest the solution to either remove or add trailing slash without redirect issues. Purpose is for SEO to avoid content duplication issue. Thank you. My nginx conf file:

```
server {
listen          8080;
server_name     xyz.de www.xyz.de;
root            /var/www/html/xyz.de;
port_in_redirect off;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/xyz.de.access.log;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/xyz.de.apachestyle.access.log  apachestandard;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/xyz.de.error.log;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /apple-touch-icon.png { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location ~ /\. { deny  all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 500 501 502 503 = @fallback;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass hhvm;
}
location @fallback {
    fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass php;
}
location ~* \.(ico|gif|jpe?g|png|svg|eot|otf|woff|woff2|ttf|ogg|js|css)$ {
    expires max;
}
```

}

Comment: Please be specific about the problem that is occurring.

Comment: If I add this in server block,  rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent; then I am getting Page isn't redirecting properly error in my browser. Thanks!

Comment: What's the permalink structure in WordPress? If it doesn't contain a trailing slash and if you try to add it in nginx, then it would result in the error "page isn't redirecting properly" that is nothing but infinite redirect.

Comment: Man you are a genius. I just needed to add a trailing slash to the permalink structure